# Could not find any actions for URL applewebdata

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink

i try to open link that tapped in app, like this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)url inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{

    UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [myApp openURL:url];

    return YES;
}
```

But in result, nothing happens.

Just: Could not find any actions for URL applewebdata://10FC0C33-238E-481E-BF44-8D0BA2B1FBB7/%22https://vk.com/feed/%22 without any result.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact error. The problem was that I declared the delegate method

```
    public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
```

in a (Swift) extension of the (Objective-C) class, but the class header had the protocol conformance declaration.

It all worked once I moved the UITextFieldDelegate declaration to the extension, where the delegate method was

```
extension MyViewController: UITextViewDelegate
```